# Can you identify this seal?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, plumbing-fixture

I have a slow-filling cistern and, having disassembled all the pipes inside I've identified a ripped seal. Assuming that I didn't cause that myself just a moment ago, I'm hopeful that replacing it will solve the problem.

Can you identify it?

[image: Image of seal in my fingers, showing the tear]
[image: Image of seal next to a 1p coin]

Comment: Is there a check valve involved?  It looks like it may fit over a post

Comment: Ahhh a W.C. cistern, was imagining house sized cistern.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a Torbeck Cistern Ball Valve Diaphragm Washer

[image]

FYI, I used google image search. I cropped the image and [searched by image](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1920&bih=995&tbs=sbi:AMhZZivGAqpIzkPj8p9NEkStKihOWUiHl20MINAuQmPghwGy4Y_1TaF1sSI1yPHHY50w5PXOzSZagDGe1Gwif7lxXDXkTGbnwTFaut66LWMMllMS34TWfhCQBm_1_1qYUeNG-MUJ3RlyLcRo-ZL88tdtPFCH4h-7R4sSIVKUtzapG-dncXn-9o7eZJ1fW7-hFfKStr7FzbbMloe2PAHRvQLDd-Yxv0jNAOgPT_1WOxHPba0X44vF2wiJDdftnd9kkb2Uc3aSX6smW3rTXHpoNwfm8mBbg1p7_1trLJ2yaLSUeS7H3HWY2wUk_1T5FY3NZ0fzs8XhJ8v-QPTzI5ayX67IrifzHOp3YxGLdx-9rDYFmfchcPbwd4j-QjOEMJrCR885CXInpsbu5eLuJSzkvpnK7MzUiA1zUI4LJCGrXk62PGlTCwOFn9IGd9H9TRMqzeJTf1fYz7n57lIECKNbXfLF9VYD48GDcRUtZHbXqR1S8bs4p3Exk4rN4QzAJKYCidS56VLcW5Uf4GgmKOLmeHnTEP1y6MaYYieD1N_1DDp0r5e-ZgZKW0rXx1QzYNyPzyjr446Kmp-zeTyINXaVDZ-4PBB5KazJ9GV8zJGRf9yF2l9OFNSXGKgNmw8lH4ATgFfCaZfqZKFOlHKodczIInufU6QJN6qDoXxRnopbNc17fhD8ZYrC5ElfAqih9I5_1xFP9PC1DjAnmhfuo8o3Ro64KHsPXQ6kWUtiICiJl2CjI8JSa_1Vn98Ipixfvr12PyzdkH2lVSe5wxWXgcxkvaacS9JKGgoo3Rk_1ueq1RwjFa502NGhpAtaws7eoYrDmHswTjzMNLI6tc7AeGZBgCArscv7Ua4yGSXzqH3GHMMiIV0HIFuLyhrV7S0KM4dPv_1c_1qYvs7j42VHczRaiN3I1DrnkG_1C5xZfT3uVQFjrKA&q=cistern%20seal&oq=cistern%20seal&gs_l=serp.3..0l3j0i22i30l7.2137.4078.0.4718.12.12.0.0.0.0.153.1209.7j5.12.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.6.serp.uY0XoHoWJao). I don't have an encyclopedic memory of seals.

Comment: The force is strong with this one.